# White page after installing user plugin

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm trying out Phalcon for the first time. I had it working locally with the skeleton. I then tried to add the user bundle from [here](https://github.com/calinrada/PhalconUserPlugin) (I know it's in alpha) and I'm getting a blank white page with HTTP code 200.

I've found that I get an actual error saying that the "auth" method is missing if I remove the following code, whereas I get a white page if I add it back:

```
$di->set('auth', function() {
    return new \Phalcon\UserPlugin\Auth\Auth();
});
```

I also found that the `public/index.php` file reaches the very end of the try block without throwing any exceptions.

Finally, I had tried removing the try/catch block completely and adding Phalcon debugger - I still get a white page.

How can I further debug this and figure out why I'm getting a white page?

Comment: Turn php error reporting on at the top of your script.

    error_reporting(-1);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

And see if that sheds on light on the white page.

Comment: Enable XDebug and use an IDE which can step through your application's code such as PHPStorm https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LUTolQw8K9A

Comment: Or you can just check apache/nginx error logs - should be some info there. Another thing - if you have white page - maybe it's just missing template? Try to var_dump something with die, and move this across your code - simpliest and yet efficient debugging ;)